# Change code to android annotations

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I'm trying to change my code to android annotations. My app starts but when I tap button it crash and get error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.albertpula.apka3, PID: 2523
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.albertpula.apka3.MainActivity$ReadPic.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:83)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
    at com.example.albertpula.apka3.MainActivity.click(MainActivity.java:54)
    at com.example.albertpula.apka3.MainActivity_$1.onClick(MainActivity_.java:72)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is code:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 String adres ="http://www.heavens-above.com/orbitdisplay.aspx?icon=iss&width=300&height=300&satid=25544";
 Bitmap bmp;
 ProgressBar progressBar;
 Button button1;
 ImageView image;
 TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Click(R.id.button1)
void click(View view){
    ReadPic rp = new ReadPic();
    rp.execute();
}

class ReadPic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    boolean sukces = true;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        URL u;
        InputStream is;
        try{

            u = new URL( adres);
            is = u.openStream();
            Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            bmp=temp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        }
        catch( Exception e){
            sukces = false;

        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        button1.setEnabled(false);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        if(sukces){
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
            Paint p = new Paint();
            int width = bmp.getWidth(), height = bmp.getHeight();
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            c.drawRect(0,0,width-1,height-1,p);

            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            text.setText("Downloading finished, img " +width+ "x" + height);
        }
        else{
            text.setText("Error when downloading");
        }
        button1.setEnabled(true);
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: logcat log aligned in single line for easy reading and formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use ViewBinding for binding your xml views like this :

   > ```
   > @ViewById(R.id.button1)Button button1;
   >
   > @ViewById(R.id.imageView)ImageView image;
   >
   > @ViewById(R.id.textView1)TextView text;
   > ```

Remove the code from your onCreate().

2. Don't add :

   > ```
   > super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   >
   > setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   > ```
3. For the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference at

**Option :1 Check if it is null.**

> ```
> protected void onPreExecute(){
>     if(progressBar != null)
>         progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
>
>     button1.setEnabled(false);
>     super.onPreExecute();
> }
> ```

AND,

> ```
> button1.setEnabled(true); 
>
> if(progressBar != null)
> progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
>
> super.onPostExecute(result);
> ```

**Option :2 - Initialize the ProgressDialog**

> ```
>  class ReadPic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
>      ProgressBar progressBar;
>      boolean sukces = true;
>
>      public ReadPic(){
>          progressBar = new ProgressBar();//Set the Theme, context & call constructor as per your choice.
>      }
>
>      //YOUR CODE GOES BELOW// 
>   }//ReadPic class closes here....
> ```

Edit 1: Gorthez, instantiate your Progress bar like this:

> `progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);`

Also Add Progress Bar in your xml:

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>       android:orientation="horizontal"
>       ... >
>         <ProgressBar
>           android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
>           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
>           android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
>       <TextView
>           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:text="@string/loading" />  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Edit1 Reference https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I delete super.onCreate... and setContentView... app crashing. BTW what can I type to set theme, context, and call constructor (Option 2)?

Comment: @Gorthez : @EActivity(R.layout.activity_main) is working perfectly fine in my code. i.e. my code is not crashing. May be your gradle sync issues (Possible). Nevertheless ! i have updated code for (Option 2), chk now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! finally works! :) I got last question. This code shows only one picture after tapp, is there much to do to show more picture after 1 tapp button?

Comment: @Gorthez : Please accept the answer if it helped. And, could you please elaborate your next question "By asking a new question". Bcoz, currently i cannot understand you doubt in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   

    **//put setContentView and super call here

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Here you are trying to access the view elements before inflating the layout.
    First inflate the layout by calling **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**
    then try to access the elements.

Comment: Thanks, it helped, app not crashed but also nothing happens when I tapping button. Any idea what else is wrong?
this is form logcat
 17985-17985/com.example.albertpula.apka3 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@aaf4482 time:1459738
17985-17985/com.example.albertpula.apka3 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
 17985-17985/com.example.albertpula.apka3 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
 17985-18239/com.example.albertpula.apka3 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Comment: protected void onPreExecute(){
 progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);  
 //add below line
 progressBar.show(); 
 button1.setEnabled(false);
 super.onPreExecute();
}

you should call progressBar.show() to get it visible

Comment: ups style for progressBar where missing.
and I can't add progressBar.show() "cannot resolve method show()"
but still nothing happens

Comment: @Gorthez: Here you are using ProgressBar, but you have nothing to show in the progress. check this Tutorial, here they are updating the progressBar https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progress_circle.htm    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progressbar.htm